# What is the ancient context of "raised you up", Ex 9:16?

Tags: hebrew, exodus, translation-philosophy

I am studying Exodus right now, and have been digging deep into the Lord hardening Pharaoh's heart. In Exodus 9:15-16, the Lord speaks through Moses to Pharaoh and says,

> <sup>**15**</sup>For by now I could have put out my hand and struck you and your people with pestilence, and you would have been cut off from the earth. <sup>**16**</sup> But for this purpose *I HAVE RAISED YOU UP*, to show you my power, so that my name may be proclaimed in all the earth." (ESV)

I think one of the key phrases that might get slightly lost in translation is "I have raised you up." What is the ancient context and literal translation for this phrase? Where else is it used? Just trying to see if there is more context or literal meaning to this than meets the eye, or if it really is like bringing one up for a purpose.

Comment: In the Hebrew, "I have raised you up" is a single word, הֶעֱמַדְתִּ֔יךָ

Answer (score 1):

In the context of the passage "I have raised you up" adds emphasis to the fact that God is it control. God put Pharaoh in power (not any other god and not Pharaoh himself).

Backing up just a little bit:

Exodus 9

> 13 Then the Lord said to Moses, “Get up early in the morning, confront Pharaoh and say to him, ‘This is what the Lord, the God of the Hebrews, says: Let my people go, so that they may worship me, 14 or this time I will send the full force of my plagues against you and against your officials and your people, so you may know that there is no one like me in all the earth.

The key part of the passage is "so you may know that there is no one like me in all the earth"

God put Pharaoh where he was, when he was, so that God could demonstrate to Pharaoh and the world that He is sovereign.

The point God is making is that He is in control.

- God put Pharaoh in power - raised him up v16
- God could have wiped Pharaoh and the Egyptians off the face of the earth v15
- God is giving Pharaoh a choice v13
- Rather than wiping Egypt off the map God is helping Pharaoh make the right choice by sending plagues (God is gracious) v14
- All this is being done to show God's glory - "there is no one like me in all the earth"

Answer (score 0):

Onkelos (an ancient Aramaic translation of the Bible) translates הֶעֱמַדְתִּ֔יךָ as קַיֵּמִתָּךְ which loosely translates to "I have allowed you to survive", or "I have left you alive"

https://www.sefaria.org.il/Onkelos%20Exodus%209:16